# d3.scaleOrdinal not returning correct range value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm having a problem getting the wrong value when calling d3.scaleOrdinal():

Here is my domain and range:

```
this.domain = ["attributed_visits", "average_cost_per_spot", "cost_per_response", "responses_per_spot", "total_cost", "total_spots"]

this.range = ["rgba(255, 56, 56, 1)", "rgba(169, 64, 152, 1)", "rgba(0, 143, 219, 1)", "rgba(93, 206, 6, 1)", "rgba(244, 212, 0, 1)", "rgba(242, 96, 0, 1)"]

        var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
        .domain(this.domain)
        .range(this.range);
```

when I call

```
z('total_cost')
```

it returns "rgba(255, 56, 56, 1)" - the first value in the range, not the fifth, "rgba(244, 212, 0, 1)" as I was expecting.

Comment: Tried your code. Works as expected. Can you post the whole code?

Comment: Thanks for checking, on stepping through the code, I'm seeing the domain array getting sliced down to a single item, so that's the problem. Thanks again for your time.

Comment: Thought so.. No problemmo @DShultz. Glad you could solve it on your own :)